# Regex match <head ...> not <header>

Tags: regex

I need a regex that can match either `<head ...>` or `<head>` but not `<header>`.

I currently have `(<head(?!:er)*>`

I succeeded in part, removing `er` with `(?!:er)` but `<head ...>` is still invalid.

Any regex expert could help? Thanks!

Comment: You need `<head(?!er>)[^<>]*>`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much!

Comment: What about `<headr>`, `<head er>`, or `<head1>`?

Comment: `<head(?=[ >])` would work too

Comment: @MonkeyZeus amazing answer too

Comment: `<head[\s>]` would work as well, without look-aheads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `<head(?!:er)*>` pattern matches `<head`, then it *optionally requires* (due to `*` at the end of the lookahead construct) if the text immediately to the right is not `:er` (here, `:` is part of the lookahead pattern, not part of a lookahead construct) and then requires a `>` char. Since `>` is not `:`, this lookahead always returns *true*.

You need something like

```js
<head(?!er>)[^<>]*>
```

where

- `<head` - matches `<head`
- `(?!er>)` - makes sure the text immediately on the right is not `er>`
- `[^<>]*>` - matches any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `>`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xorLzH/1).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation